# Redirect page to login page using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to redirect http://demo.pageinvasion.com/?action=logout&_wpnonce=9615dd028c to http://demo.pageinvasion.com/wp-login.php?loggedout=true using htaccess

Comment: please show us what you tried so far, and explain how it fails

Comment: ... [Use htaccess mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/remapping.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code in your htaccess file. This may help you.

```
# 301 --- http://demo.pageinvasion.com/?pg_track=request_demo&un=demo => http://demo.pageinvasion.com/wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pg_track=request_demo($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)un=demo($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /wp-login.php? [L,R=301]

# 301 --- http://demo.pageinvasion.com/ => http://demo.pageinvasion.com/wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^$ /wp-login.php? [L,R=301]
```